# Problems in deploying Hbase standalone mode in ubuntu

Tags: hbase

I'm a beginner of Hbase. I totally followed the quick-start docs in http://hbase.apache.org/quickstart.html and I want to run Hbase in a **standalone** mode.

and I changed the hbase-site.xml a little:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file://home/archer/HbaseData</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Then I went into Hbase shell and typed command:

```
create 'test', 'cf'
```

After running for a very long(about 1 hours). It shows

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=7, exceptions:
Sun Mar 11 15:34:42 PDT 2012, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable@815e0c, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for test3,,00000000000000 after 7 tries.
Sun Mar 11 15:41:43 PDT 2012, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable@815e0c, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for test3,,00000000000000 after 7 tries.
Sun Mar 11 15:48:44 PDT 2012, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable@815e0c, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for test3,,00000000000000 after 7 tries.
Sun Mar 11 15:55:45 PDT 2012, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable@815e0c, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for test3,,00000000000000 after 7 tries.
Sun Mar 11 16:02:47 PDT 2012, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable@815e0c, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for test3,,00000000000000 after 7 tries.
Sun Mar 11 16:09:49 PDT 2012, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable@815e0c, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for test3,,00000000000000 after 7 tries.
Sun Mar 11 16:16:53 PDT 2012, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable@815e0c, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for test3,,00000000000000 after 7 tries.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I'm using ubuntu 11.10 and jdk7.0 and I havn't installed any hadoop or zookeeper before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes i have faced this problem too but with hdfs based installation , for which just make sure that the address which you provide in the config files across your cluster of hadoop, hbase, zookeeper ( may be single node also ) is resolved properly.

in your case i think it is due to

```
<value>file:///home/archer/HbaseData</value>
```

Notice the missing forward slash.

Comment: Do I need to separately install hadoop and zookeeper to run the standalone mode?

Comment: no you do not i was just making a point,,just try to put a forward slash, if you want a full hdfs based setup try this http://openwires.blogspot.in/p/hbase-setup.html

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://search-hadoop.com/m/3QwOgkWbob2&subj=Install+hbase+on+Ubuntu+11+10) should be answer on your problems.

**EDITED** 
I don't know know what it can be. regionserver service is not needed in standalone version. You have to starts it only in distributed mode.

But if you have problems and it is your first HBase installation i strongly recommended to you a cloudera HBase version. The documentation is much better and everything is described very well. [HERE](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/HBase+Installation) you have installation guide.

Comment: Do I need to separately install hadoop and zookeeper to run the standalone mode?

Answer (score 0):

```
<value>file:///home/archer/HbaseData</value>
```

forward slash missed
In addition to this change owner ship of HbaseData using following

```
sudo chown -R <username>:<groupname> /home/archer/HbaseData
```

Note:If till not works then simply create directory as follows /home//hbase     and /home//zookeeper

Set as follows in hbase-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>file:///home/<username>/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/home/<username>/zookeeper</value>
```